# Single Classifier network in Torch

Tags: neural-network, torch

I am new to Torch.
I am trying to run single classifier Experiment in Torch.But,I am getting the following error when Training is started,

**/torch/install/bin/luajit: bad argument #2 to '?' (out of range at /torch/pkg/torch/generic/Tensor.c:853)**

**stack traceback:**

```
    [C]: at 0x7f17b9dc029
    [C]: in function '__index'
    .../torch/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/ConfusionMatrix.lua:40: in function '_add'
    .../torch/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/ConfusionMatrix.lua:102: in function 'batchAdd'
    Main.lua:246: in function 'Train'
    Main.lua:289: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    .../torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:131: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

Is it possible to train single classifier network in Torch?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Heh, it's pretty difficult to help with your script without seeing it. Maybe you should attach the source code of this "single classifier Experiment"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.
My model contains,

classifier = nn.Sequential()

classifier:add(nn.Dropout(0.5))

classifier:add(nn.Linear(512,512))

classifier:add(nn.BatchNormalization(512))

classifier:add(nn.ReLU(true))

classifier:add(nn.Dropout(0.5))

classifier:add(nn.Linear(512,1))

classifier:add(nn.LogSoftMax())

and I am using  **nn.CrossEntropyCriterion()** for Loss in the network.

Is it possible to run single classifier experiment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can train in one class.

The error you got is pointing towards confusion matrix.
For one class it should be in the following way:
-- classes

```
classes = {1}
```

-- This matrix records the current confusion across classes

```
confusion = optim.ConfusionMatrix(classes)
```

Your train labels or test labels should never contain '0' number as the label.